# How to display a table from another website using iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to make use of iframe to pick a particular table and the info it's been populated with from a particular website and make it appear on mine. I only need the table to be iframed. Here's the website: ***https://realnaps.com/signal***

I need to pick the just that table that's been populated with the results. Please, is there anyone who can help with this? When I tried iframe it picked the whole webpage but I don't want the whole webpage, I only want the table that is been populated. Thanks in advance.

*This is how the table looks like:*

[image: table]

Comment: Can you give more information? A code example?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This is the div controlling the table.

<div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 8px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 6px 20px 0px; width: 80%; border-radius: none; margin: 15px 0px;" class="dragMe" id="gameBox"><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><th> SEASON/ DAY</th><th>TEAMS</th><th>BET</th></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: What is your current code? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here is the current code I applied:
<iframe src="https://realnaps.com/signal" height="200" width="300" title="VFL prediction"></iframe>

Comment: What is the python code that you have tried? Edit your submission with using this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I haven't tried out any python codes yet as I am not very vast on Python. I am just starting out on Python. Been honest.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to embed just a portion of a document in an iframe with just HTML.

You will have to write some JS code to poll that site and extract just the desired content.

But, have you noticed that there is a published websocket? You may also try to get the data via JS: wss://realnaps.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=tXNlXGWrZl-pipLxAMR_

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a try just now.

Comment: Hi, i tried it but i don't think I am getting it right. can you help me with the code please?